# Get count of how many batch from parcels made in every hour of the day

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am very confused with `DISTINCT`, `GROUP BY` clauses and can't get my head around what I need to do to get my desired values.

My table (simplified)

```
CREATE TABLE manufacturing
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [dt] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [parcel_id] [int] NULL,
    [batch_no] [int] NULL,
    [tn] [int] NULL
)
GO
```

Every parcel_id has batch_no 1 to 'anything' and batch_no has tn 1 to 'anything' so they are not fixed max numbers.

When a machine completes a step (tn) it writes it to DB

I need to get how many batches there in db for every hour (from 0 to 24)

A batch can start at 15:00 and finish at 17:00 I need to write that to 17.

What I tried is

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(parcel_batch) AS batch_count, dt
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         parcel_batch as parcel_batch, MAX(dt) as dt
     FROM 
         (SELECT DISTINCT(CONVERT(varchar, parcel_id) + CONVERT(varchar, batch_no)) as parcel_batch, DATEPART(HOUR, dt) as dt
          FROM manufacturing 
          WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, dt) = 2021 
            AND DATEPART(MONTH, dt) = 09 
            AND DATEPART(DAY, dt) = 15 
            AND fabrika = 2) AS qq 
     GROUP BY
         parcel_batch) AS new 
GROUP BY
    dt
```

What I tried at the 1st query (Line 3) was combining parcel and batch can give me unique number so I can DISTINCT. It seemed like it worked at first, with my test values. Then I used it on real db (which is much much more large) it doesn't give correctly.

I get my total batch for today like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT rh.parcel_id, CONVERT(varchar, MIN(rh.dt)), CONVERT(varchar, MAX(rh.dt)), MAX(rh.batch_no) FROM manufacturing as rh
WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, rh.dt) = DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())
AND DATEPART(MONTH, rh.dt) = DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE())
AND DATEPART(DAY, rh.dt) = DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE())
GROUP BY rh.parcel_id
```

But really couldn't figure out how to get how many batches for every hour since I couldn't get my head around DISTINCT (I guess it takes everything after SELECT, I thought only 1st one or something) or GROUP BY

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

This is what my data looks like.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    INSERT INTO manufacturing VALUES(CONVERT(datetime,'2021-09-15 00:03:00.000'), 290, 1, 45)
    INSERT INTO manufacturing VALUES(CONVERT(datetime,'2021-09-15 00:05:00.000'), 290, 1, 48)
    INSERT INTO manufacturing VALUES(CONVERT(datetime,'2021-09-15 00:34:00.000'), 290, 2, 44)
    INSERT INTO manufacturing VALUES(CONVERT(datetime,'2021-09-15 00:47:00.000'), 291, 1, 58)
    INSERT INTO manufacturing VALUES(CONVERT(datetime,'2021-09-15 00:54:00.000'), 291, 1, 43)
    INSERT INTO manufacturing VALUES(CONVERT(datetime,'2021-09-15 00:58:00.000'), 291, 1, 43)
    INSERT INTO manufacturing VALUES(CONVERT(datetime,'2021-09-15 01:02:00.000'), 291, 1, 2)
    INSERT INTO manufacturing VALUES(CONVERT(datetime,'2021-09-15 01:08:00.000'), 291, 1, 41)
    INSERT INTO manufacturing VALUES(CONVERT(datetime,'2021-09-15 01:24:00.000'), 291, 2, 46)
    INSERT INTO manufacturing VALUES(CONVERT(datetime,'2021-09-15 01:36:00.000'), 291, 2, 47)
    INSERT INTO manufacturing VALUES(CONVERT(datetime,'2021-09-15 01:58:00.000'), 291, 3, 2)
    INSERT INTO manufacturing VALUES(CONVERT(datetime,'2021-09-15 02:04:00.000'), 291, 3, 42)
    INSERT INTO manufacturing VALUES(CONVERT(datetime,'2021-09-15 02:23:00.000'), 291, 3, 52)
    INSERT INTO manufacturing VALUES(CONVERT(datetime,'2021-09-15 02:54:00.000'), 292, 1, 57)
    INSERT INTO manufacturing VALUES(CONVERT(datetime,'2021-09-15 02:55:00.000'), 292, 1, 53)
    INSERT INTO manufacturing VALUES(CONVERT(datetime,'2021-09-15 02:59:00.000'), 292, 2, 48)
    INSERT INTO manufacturing VALUES(CONVERT(datetime,'2021-09-15 03:12:00.000'), 292, 2, 45)
    INSERT INTO manufacturing VALUES(CONVERT(datetime,'2021-09-15 03:15:00.000'), 292, 2, 44)
    INSERT INTO manufacturing VALUES(CONVERT(datetime,'2021-09-15 03:22:00.000'), 292, 3, 51)
    INSERT INTO manufacturing VALUES(CONVERT(datetime,'2021-09-15 03:46:00.000'), 293, 1, 58)
    INSERT INTO manufacturing VALUES(CONVERT(datetime,'2021-09-15 03:55:00.000'), 293, 1, 2)
    INSERT INTO manufacturing VALUES(CONVERT(datetime,'2021-09-15 04:24:00.000'), 293, 2, 2)
    INSERT INTO manufacturing VALUES(CONVERT(datetime,'2021-09-15 04:33:00.000'), 293, 2, 2)
    INSERT INTO manufacturing VALUES(CONVERT(datetime,'2021-09-15 04:45:00.000'), 294, 1, 2)
    INSERT INTO manufacturing VALUES(CONVERT(datetime,'2021-09-15 04:46:00.000'), 294, 1, 57)
    INSERT INTO manufacturing VALUES(CONVERT(datetime,'2021-09-15 04:58:00.000'), 294, 1, 1)
    INSERT INTO manufacturing VALUES(CONVERT(datetime,'2021-09-15 05:23:00.000'), 295, 1, 1)
    INSERT INTO manufacturing VALUES(CONVERT(datetime,'2021-09-15 05:32:00.000'), 295, 1, 53)
    INSERT INTO manufacturing VALUES(CONVERT(datetime,'2021-09-15 05:35:00.000'), 295, 2, 51)
    INSERT INTO manufacturing VALUES(CONVERT(datetime,'2021-09-15 05:38:00.000'), 295, 3, 1)
    INSERT INTO manufacturing VALUES(CONVERT(datetime,'2021-09-15 05:43:00.000'), 296, 1, 52)
    INSERT INTO manufacturing VALUES(CONVERT(datetime,'2021-09-15 05:47:00.000'), 296, 1, 52)
    INSERT INTO manufacturing VALUES(CONVERT(datetime,'2021-09-15 05:49:00.000'), 296, 1, 52)
    INSERT INTO manufacturing VALUES(CONVERT(datetime,'2021-09-15 06:45:00.000'), 296, 1, 2)
    INSERT INTO manufacturing VALUES(CONVERT(datetime,'2021-09-15 06:47:00.000'), 296, 2, 2)
    INSERT INTO manufacturing VALUES(CONVERT(datetime,'2021-09-15 06:53:00.000'), 296, 2, 2)
    INSERT INTO manufacturing VALUES(CONVERT(datetime,'2021-09-15 06:56:00.000'), 296, 2, 3)
    INSERT INTO manufacturing VALUES(CONVERT(datetime,'2021-09-15 06:58:00.000'), 296, 3, 7)
    INSERT INTO manufacturing VALUES(CONVERT(datetime,'2021-09-15 07:26:00.000'), 296, 3, 1)
    INSERT INTO manufacturing VALUES(CONVERT(datetime,'2021-09-15 07:35:00.000'), 296, 4, 1)
    INSERT INTO manufacturing VALUES(CONVERT(datetime,'2021-09-15 07:42:00.000'), 296, 5, 43)
    INSERT INTO manufacturing VALUES(CONVERT(datetime,'2021-09-15 07:46:00.000'), 296, 5, 43)

SELECT * FROM manufacturing
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

What I need the output from table above:

```
-------------------
| dt | batch_count|
-------------------
| 0  |      2     |
| 1  |      2     |
| 2  |      2     |
| 3  |      3     |
| 4  |      2     |
| 5  |      3     |
| 6  |      2     |
| 7  |      3     |
-------------------
```

Total of 18 divided by hours.

Comment: GROUP BY combined with SELECT DISTINCT?!?

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the first few rows of the table for context?  Note that if group by is applied, then select distinct should be redundant

Comment: I think we need to ignore your query attempt, for clarity include actual sample data and expected result in your question as per [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You use the date datatype instead of looking at every part of a datetime. Also when using varchar you ALWAYS need to specify the precision. Otherwise it will use the default, and this can be different depending on usage.

Comment: To elaborate on @jarlh 's confusion, when you have a `GROUP BY` and `DISTINCT` in the same scope this is always a sign of a flaw. `GROUP BY` will; already be putting your data into *distinct* groups. This either means that your `GROUP BY` is wrong and dividing your data into too many groups (and so needs to be addressed and fixed), or the `DISTINCT` is completely redundant and is just causing unneeded overhead. In *both* cases the `DISTINCT` should be removed. For your SQL, this looks like the latter.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for clarifying. I knew something was off, I am really not good with SQL and lack of intellisense makes me prune to mistakes I guess. I simply thought I am grouping then SELECTing DISTINC from that grouping.

Comment: @Stu I updated the quesiton with little bit of sample data. That is just somewhere at the start though, I don't really know how I can turn it into minimal with 3000+ row. Parcels starts at anytime, ends at anytime. Those parcels' batches start at anytime, ends at anytime. If a batch started but ended an hour later. I only need to count the batch at the latter hour. I hope I am successful at describing this.

Comment: @Reotte adding images of your data is of no use to anyone, you can't cut and paste an image into sql server in order to help with a solution; add your data as *text* in your question; did you even read the [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) page?

Comment: @Stu Oh I am sorry. I honestly just glanced at page didn't read it. I thought I couldn't describe it well so you wanted to see what the table looks like. I just read the link and made a table just for this purpose. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: @Reotte I don't understand your expected results, eg you want a count of 2 for hour 01:00, your sample data has 3 different batch_no in this hour, why is the count 2 and not 3?

Comment: @Stu Because batch_no 3 of parcel 291 ends at 02:00 I want to count it when it is finished. (on the hour where the last datetime it has) So its doesn't count it for two times like 1 at 01:00 and 1 at 02:00. I only need the latest to count.

Comment: @Reotte ok thanks for the clarification. In which case I can get your desired results except for hour #4 - parcel_id 293 batch 2 and parcel_id 294 batch 1 both only exist in this hour so that's 2 batches, not 1?

Comment: @Stu Ah yes my bad, I made a picture to count correctly and fixed the question. Yes the Hour #4 should be 2 not 1. https://prnt.sc/1sf94rs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with my own solution and looks like it works flawlessly. What I do is group by parcel and batch no first so I only get 1 parcel_id and one of all batch numbers of it with their max hour.

Then from this query I group the results by hours while counting how many batches in that hour. That gives me the expected result flawlessly.

```
SELECT grp.dt, COUNT(grp.batch_no) batch_count
FROM (
     SELECT MAX(DATEPART(HOUR, dt)) dt, batch_no
     FROM manufacturing
          WHERE dt >= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
     GROUP BY parcel_id, batch_no
     ) grp
GROUP BY grp.dt
```

Also thanks for pointing out the easier datetime comparison and clarifying `GROUP BY` and `DISTINCT` clauses.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following obtains your desired results. It's still counting the distinct batches per hour, but *excludes* the batches you don't want to count because they don't end in the current hour. The date range fitering is not relevant to the issue, you can add that in where necessary.

```
select DatePart(hour, dt) hr, Count(distinct batch_no) batch_count
from manufacturing m
    where not exists (
        select * from manufacturing m2 
        where m2.parcel_id=m.parcel_id 
            and m2.batch_no=m.batch_no 
            and DatePart(hour, m2.dt)>DatePart(hour, m.dt)
    )
group by DatePart(hour, dt)
```

Comment: I really appreciete the help but there seems to be an issue. I am adding date range and got another query to get the total of each parcel_id which I am pretty sure it outputs correct values. But this answer gives me less than what it is supposed to be. So it looks like it passes on some of the values. https://prnt.sc/1sk6r3t

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be describing:

```
SELECT parcel_id, DATEPART(hour, rh.dt), COUNT(DISTINCT rh.batch_no)
FROM manufacturing rh
WHERE rh.dt >= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) AND
      rh.dt < DATEADD(DAY, 1, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
GROUP BY rh.parcel_id, DATEPART(hour, rh.dt);
```

Note the simplifications made to the date comparisons.

Comment: Thanks for clarifications on date comparisons. I didn't know you could do that.
I guess the answer is a step away from what I need. This is the result I got from the query: https://prnt.sc/1senywx 
As you can see there are double hours. I need it more like this: https://prnt.sc/1seobyh

I did try to remove the parcel_id from both select and group by and it actually gave me what I need like so: https://prnt.sc/1seogt3 BUT there is a mistake. at dt column combining 8 would give 8 batch count but when I remove parcel_id I get 7.

I think I am missing something.

Comment: @Reotte . . . Your query attempt includes `parcel_id`, so that seems important vis-a-vis the question.  Your question should really include sample data and desired results.

Comment: Yes, but it wasn't to get the parcel id but to get a unique number combining parcel id and batch number because I didn't know what to do. I know its silly attempt. Also included the sample data and desired results.